# Android SQLite Error: (1) near "Create": syntax error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am having problems with the creation of my SQLite Database. This is the error I get:

> (1) near "CREATE": syntax error.

Code:

```
db.execSQL(context.getString(R.string.sql_create))
```

SQL:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Categories` (
    `idCategories` INT NOT NULL ,
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
     PRIMARY KEY (`idCategories`)
)

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Stores` (
    `idStores` INT NOT NULL ,
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
    `locationAdress` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
    `locationLongitude` INT NULL ,
    `locationLatitude` INT NULL ,
    `category` INT NOT NULL ,
    `telephoneNumerber` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idStores`) ,
    INDEX `category_idx` (`category` ASC) ,
    CONSTRAINT `category` FOREIGN KEY (`category` )
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`Categories` (`idCategories` )
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `OpeningHours` (
    `idOpeningHours` INT NOT NULL ,
    `store` INT NOT NULL ,
    `day` INT NULL ,
    `forenoon` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
    `afternoon` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idOpeningHours`) ,
    INDEX `store_idx` (`store` ASC) ,
    CONSTRAINT `store` FOREIGN KEY (`store` )
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`Stores` (`idStores` )
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

I really don´t know whats wrong with the sql code, I hope someone here can help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in my SQLite syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609474/error-in-my-sqlite-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copied from here: [Error in my SQLite syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609474/error-in-my-sqlite-syntax)

> put a semicolon after each statement.

```
CREATE TABLE ( ... ) ;
CREATE TABLE ( ... ) ;
```

Comment: what a stupid mistake....thanks ;) i`ll try it tomorrow